# Does voting count work on mobile site of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, mobile-web, vote-count

I have gotten the ["see vote counts" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) on Stack Overflow, and I visited a lot of downvoted and upvoted posts on Stack Overflow on the mobile site, but I can't see number of upvotes and downvotes.

Does the mobile site not support it?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108769/248731

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No; the mobile version of Stack Exchange does not support viewing vote counts:

> The gotcha is that a lot of android phones really don't have the click accuracy you need to distinguish between up vote, down vote, and show vote split clicks. It's really quite frustrating trying to vote and accidentally displaying votes or vice versus.
>
> Since it's such low priority information, I pulled it. We might revisit this when the balance of android browsers shifts, I hear through the grape vine it's gotten a lot better in the latest and greatest versions. Still too many old ones out there right now though.
> <sub>[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108769/show-the-number-of-up-votes-and-down-votes-on-the-mobile-site-theme/111090#111090)</sub>

A workaround would be to switch the desktop version by clicking the link in the footer or to use the Stack Exchange mobile app ([iOS](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/) | [Android](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/)), which does support this feature.

Comment: I end up accidentally upvoting or downvoting when I try to click on the number *and it doesn't work.* The big friendly number is hard to miss (I'm not on an Android handset, though).

Comment: @tripleee On the app? To access vote counts there, you tap and hold.

Comment: No, in the mobile view in my regular browser on my iPhone.  You can verify the same (even on a desktop) by visiting the little "mobile" link in the footer of this page. (Click "full site" in the footer to revert to the desktop skin.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the new [responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes), viewing the vote counts is now supported on mobile.

[image: before clicking the score]
[image: after clicking the score]

Comment: Only when using the full site version from the footer, which the other answer already provided as a work around

Comment: @NickA The "old" mobile skin will be removed, there won't be a 'full site' link to click on. I posted this answer because I became so used to vote counts not working on mobile, that it took me a while to realise it is possible now, and others may be in the same boat.

Comment: *"there **won't** be a 'full site'"* *"I became so used to vote counts not working on mobile, that it took me a while to realise **it is possible now**"* I don't understand. Do you mean it is available or will be? On my mobile I'm unable to view vote counts unless on the "full site"

Comment: @NickA did you perhaps [disable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369427/what-is-disable-responsiveness-in-the-footer-section-of-stack-overflow) the new design or opt-out of it in some other way? I assume on mobile you don't see the same as in the screenshots I posted?

Comment: I haven't, and indeed, I see the version prior to the responsive design update

Comment: **It doesn't work for me**, the accepted answer still the correct one as of Nov 2018.

Comment: @gsamaras then you're still using the mobile site. It only works when you use the responsive design, by switching over to the desktop site on your phone.