# What is "Disable Responsiveness" in the footer section of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, footer, design

What does the "Disable Responsiveness" link actually do?

And why is this link out there in the footer (instead of settings may be)? I am seeing this link in the footer of the Stack Overflow site only and not on any other site.

[image: Disable responsiveness link below Mobile]

Comment: It is also on Meta Stack Overflow (this site) - if it can be considered a separate site.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the window gets small enough, the layout of the page changes to adapt to the width. When you disable responsiveness, the page sets a minimum width which it will keep regardless of screen width.

With this you can for example make sure stuff doesn't wrap on a small screen (if you don't want it to).

Comment: Oh I see! Pretty interesting! So I just played using Chrome's device toolbar and it actually worked. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I never would have guessed that is what it meant.  Perhaps it could be relabeled (or have title text) *fixed minimum window width* or something along those lines.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is *probably* temporary. It's only used in case the responsiveness prevents you from using the site properly. When SE gets all the flaws worked out, the responsiveness will become permanent.