# What is the use case of "Disable Responsiveness"?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, debugging-questions

There is [What is "Disable Responsiveness" in the footer section of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369427/1737973) but they missed the reasons anyone could want to disable responsiveness.

I mean I've witnessed crappy responsive sites where some widths are broken, but assuming the programming and styling is completely correct, why would anyone want to disable responsiveness?

Comment: I just don't like it, I'm glad we can disable it.

Answer (score 6):

Some users have [special needs and preferences](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

Their browser's window may be of the size where the responsive mode squeezes main text area more than they would like.

Or, the responsive mode drops the right sidebar all the way to the bottom and they don't like that, preferring to scroll.

Or, they don't like seeing the right sidebar at all and size the window so that it's out of the view.

Or, they could be on a site that uses MathJax which is a whole another bag of surprises as far as responsiveness is concerned.

Not to mention that this setting may well be temporary and provided only while the company considers its responsive design a work in progress.