# How can we zoom the website out after the "Disable Responsiveness" option was removed?

Tags: discussion, support, browser-support

After the ["Disable Responsiveness"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376137/what-is-the-use-case-of-disable-responsiveness) option was removed, one can no longer zoom the web.

Also, the handy columns, normally located on the right, namely **Custom Filters**, **Watched Tags**,
**Related Tags**, and **Hot Network Questions** are very hard to access, hidden by many screens to be scrolled. At least in **Firefox Mobile**.

Now it looks like the screenshot below, which is really, really, *really long* and painful to scroll all the way down. At least in Firefox.

How can this be rectified?

<sup>Click the image for a larger version</sup>

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: @KevinB The enormous image being hard to read is the whole point. All I want is that be nicer to use and read. I also  find the solution to be lacking. I have not accepted my answer.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that a view tailored for mobile is harder to read on mobile than a view that isn't. Regardless of what other issues i have with the new design.

Comment: There's a button at the bottom of the results that would significantly reduce the height of the results

Comment: Rage quitting is an immature reaction. Instead, I suggest taking a [wikiholiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikibreak) of, say, three weeks. That would include ***logging out*** of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't consider the obvious. You're complaining about content being far down the page when you've set it to show 50 posts per page. Set it to 15?

Comment: @Nick That button is available on that specific screen. It is **NOT** available on the home page. So to actually get to those watched tag I am showing you simply have to get all the way down.

Answer (score -4):

The way to get a reasonable experience on a mobile device now is to force **Desktop site** - at least in Firefox.

Having to do that every time is very unfortunate, though. To be able to force Desktop site, one can use the **Firefox Beta** version of the app.

Zoomed out initial view:
[image: Zoomed out initial view]

Double tap to zoom in:
[image: Double tap to zoom in]