# Why does Stack Overflow look like this?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, mobile-web, design

Out of curiosity, I clicked at the link at the bottom of Stack Overflow, *Disable Responsiveness*, on mobile iPhone... Then I refreshed the page, and instead of the default Stack Overflow appearance (UI), I got this:

> [image: Scrn1]

When I refreshed the page it got back to normal, but this got me curious.

So I checked, and it seems this is the same appearance as some other Stack Exchange communities. Stack Overflow has a different appearance, though. So why did it appear differently?

I couldn't replicate it again. Is this just a bug, or is this what *Disable Responsiveness* does?

**Note:** It was asked in the comments how Stack Overflow looks like normally, so here:

> [image: Image 2]

Comment: Did you mistakenly click "Mobile" at the bottom? What you described used to be  the intended  behavior, but something(s) seems to be changed.

Comment: I just clicked "Disable Responsiveness". Don't know why this happens. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "Disable Responsiveness" in the footer section of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369427/what-is-disable-responsiveness-in-the-footer-section-of-stack-overflow)

Comment: I'm starting to think this isn't related to *Disable Responsiveness*. Perhaps this is a proxy problem?

Comment: Still not clear where there is a "problem". Were you surprised that dark mode was disabled?

Comment: This is not the appearance of Stack Overflow, even with dark mode disabled. It seems like some sort of old version of the current UI.